# Creating each row of excel data into xml files using VBA Macro

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am trying to create each row (Specific Columns) of Excel data into xml files (with tags) using VBA Macro. I am able to create the files but data is not populating into xml files. Please help me!!

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub SaveAs_XML()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle    
    Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim root As IXMLDOMElement, dataNode As IXMLDOMElement, lastnameNode As IXMLDOMElement, AgeNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim dataNameAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute, Attrib As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim nameAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute, lastnameAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute, AgeAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim WS_Src As Worksheet, rng As Range, C As Range, d As Range
    Dim fs, f, ts, s
    Dim XDoc

    Folder = "\C:\New folder\"
    Set WS_Src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
    Set rng = WS_Src.Range("B1", WS_Src.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each C In rng
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        fs.CreateTextFile Folder & C.Value & ".xml"
        Set f = fs.GetFile(Folder & C.Value & ".xml")
    Next

    Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    ' DECLARE XML DOC OBJECT '
    Set root = doc.createElement("list")
    doc.appendChild root

    ' WRITE TO XML '
    For i = 2 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count 
            ' DATA NODE '
            Set dataNode = doc.createElement("data")
            root.appendChild dataNode
            ' NAME ATTRIBUTE '
            Set dataNameAttrib = doc.createAttribute("name")
            dataNameAttrib.Value = Range("B" & i)
            dataNode.setAttributeNode dataNameAttrib
            ' LASTNAME ATTRIBUTE '
            Set lastnameAttrib = doc.createAttribute("lastname")
            lastnameAttrib.Value = Range("C" & i)
            lastnameNode.setAttributeNode lastnameAttrib            
            ' AGE ATTRIBUTE '
            Set AgeAttrib = doc.createAttribute("age")
            AgeAttrib.Value = Range("E" & i)
            AgeNode.setAttributeNode AgeAttrib           

    Next i

        ' PRETTY PRINT RAW OUTPUT '
        xslDoc.LoadXML "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
            & "<xsl:stylesheet version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) _
            & "                xmlns:xsl=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" & Chr(34) & ">" _
            & "<xsl:strip-space elements=" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
            & "<xsl:output method=" & Chr(34) & "xml" & Chr(34) & " indent=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "" _
            & "            encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "/>" _
            & " <xsl:template match=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & ">" _
            & "  <xsl:copy>" _
            & "   <xsl:apply-templates select=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
            & "  </xsl:copy>" _
            & " </xsl:template>" _
            & "</xsl:stylesheet>"

        xslDoc.async = False  


    MsgBox "Successfully exported Excel data to XML!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I want output to be something like this (xml file) for each row

```
$ Output

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List>
    <Data name="test1" 
     lastname="lastname1" 
     age ="24"
    />        
</List>
```

Comment: You're creating the xml but then you don't save it anywhere?  What's the purpose of the file creation prior to the XML loop? And what do you mean to do with the xsl document?

Comment: Can any one help me guys... please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need.  No xsl, but that doesn't matter.

Your question seems to have code sections which are somewhat disconnected from each other, so I made a few guesses about what exactly you're wanting to do.

```
Private Sub SaveAs_XML()

    Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, pi
    Dim root As IXMLDOMElement, dataNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

        Set root = doc.createElement("list")
        doc.appendChild root

        Set dataNode = doc.createElement("data")
        root.appendChild dataNode

        AddAttributeWithValue dataNode, "name", Range("B" & i)
        AddAttributeWithValue dataNode, "lastname", Range("C" & i)
        AddAttributeWithValue dataNode, "age", Range("E" & i)

        Set pi = doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0""")
        doc.InsertBefore pi, doc.ChildNodes.Item(0)

        doc.Save "C:\_Stuff\xml\" & Range("B" & i).Value & ".xml"
    Next i

    MsgBox "Successfully exported Excel data to XML!", vbInformation

End Sub

'utility: add an attribute (with a value) to an element
Sub AddAttributeWithValue(el As IXMLDOMElement, attName, attValue)
    Dim att
    Set att = el.OwnerDocument.createAttribute(attName)
    att.Value = attValue
    el.setAttributeNode att
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked very well. I have one more question. How can I save each file name with data in the name column for each row?

Comment: You should post a new question for this