# Using PDFMaker addin with Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using the Adobe PDFMaker addin with Outlook 2013.

I am using the library PDFMOutlook 1.0 Type Library which gives a PDFMaker class.

The class provides the methods CreatePDFFromEntryID and CreatePDF.

CreatePDFFromEntryID take as parameters the entryID, a boolean indicating if the entry is a folder and an output path for the file.

This code will generate a basic PDF of the contents of the passed folder ID:

```
Sub BasicPDF(sFolderID As String, sFilename As String)
    Dim objPDFMaker As PDFMOUTLOOKLib.PDFMaker
    Dim i As Integer

    'Find PDFMaker addin
    For i = 1 To Application.COMAddIns.Count
        If InStr(UCase(Application.COMAddIns.Item(i).Description), "PDFMAKER") > 0 Then
            Set objPDFMaker = Application.COMAddIns.Item(i).Object
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'If not found, show error message
    If objPDFMaker Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cannot Find PDFMaker add-in", vbOKOnly, ""
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create PDF of contents of folder
    objPDFMaker.CreatePDFFromEntryID sFolderID, True, sFilename

    'Tidy up
    Set objPDFMaker = Nothing
End Sub
```

I would like to create a portfolio PDF.

By using the CreatePDF method, PDFMaker creates an enhanced PDF of the items currently selected in the Explorer.

CreatePDF takes as a parameter "xmlConfigFile As String" but I have been unable to find any documentation or examples of what the XML string/file needs to contain.

The pages [Saving multiple e-mails to pdf with PDFMAKER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723984/saving-multiple-e-mails-to-pdf-with-pdfmaker) and [Use PDFMaker with MS Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401092/use-pdfmaker-with-ms-outlook) are the closest I have found on StackOverflow but both of these were trying to use the "AdobePDFMakerForOffice" library rather than "PDFMOutlook" and neither appears to have a working solution.

Does anybody have an example of how to pass parameters to PDFMaker as an XML string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could convert parameters to xml using the below code:

```
Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, pi
    Dim root As IXMLDOMElement, dataNode As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

        Set root = doc.createElement("list")
        doc.appendChild root

        Set dataNode = doc.createElement("data")
        root.appendChild dataNode

        AddAttributeWithValue dataNode, "name", Range("B" & i)
        AddAttributeWithValue dataNode, "lastname", Range("C" & i)
        AddAttributeWithValue dataNode, "age", Range("E" & i)

        Set pi = doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0""")
        doc.InsertBefore pi, doc.ChildNodes.Item(0)

        doc.Save "C:\_Stuff\xml\" & Range("B" & i).Value & ".xml"
    Next i

    MsgBox "Successfully exported Excel data to XML!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Reference from:

[Creating each row of excel data into xml files using VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991425/creating-each-row-of-excel-data-into-xml-files-using-vba-macro)

Comment: I don't have an issue generating XML.  It just seems like there is no documentation for PDFMaker that shows what parameters the XML needs to contain.